# Show the Hankel Transform of Rect is Jinc

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to show that the Hankel transform of the rect function is the jinc function.

The Hankel transform is defined as follows:
$$
  F(q) = \mathbb{H}\left\{f(r)\right\} = 2\pi\int_0^\infty 
         f(r) \hspace{1 mm} J_0\left(2\pi rq\right) 
         \hspace{1 mm} r \hspace{1 mm} dr
$$
where $J_0$ is the bessel function of the first kind zeroth order.

$$
  \text{rect}(x) = 
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        1 & |x| \leq 1/2 \\
        0 & |x| \gt  1/2 \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
$$

jinc is defined as
$$
  \text{jinc}(q) = \frac{J_1(\pi q)}{2q}
$$
where $J_1$ is the bessel function of the first kind, first order.

Thank you all very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would rather define $f(r)$ as follows:

$$ f(r) = \begin{cases} 1 & r \in [0,1] \\ 0 & r>1 \\ \end{cases}$$

Then use the fact that

$$ \int dx \: x J_0(x) = - x J_0'(x) + C = x J_1(x) + C $$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  The integration follows directly from the differential equation for $J_0$:

$$x J_0'' + J_0' + x J_0 = (x J_0')' + x J_0 = 0 $$

Then your Hankel transform becomes

$$ 2 \pi \int_0^1 dr \: r \, J_0(2 \pi q r) = \frac{2 \pi}{(2 \pi q )^2} 2 \pi q \, J_1(2 \pi q) = \frac{J_1(2 \pi q)}{q} $$

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're right.  Sorry; I didn't even get the problem right.